# Get the url-sheet from an other cell in Importrange

Tags: google-sheets, importrange

I am looking for a way to change the url in an importrange without actually opening the formula, but just changing the url in an other cell.
I tried with putting the cell reference, with the hyperlink function, with or without ".", but it doesn't work. Is it something that can be done ?

I am looking for a formula that can do this :

```
=Importrange(get link in cell A2;"TAB!B1:B1")
```

Comment: Hello @Anaelle, what sort of error are you getting? `=Importrange(A2, "TAB!B1")` Should work just fine.